# java.lang.IllegalStateException в ViewPager после обновления списка

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Я подгружаю контент в ViewPager используя REST-запросы. подгрузил, 3 картинки. после того как они проскролливаются , подгружаю еще 3. И именно в этот момент получаю экзепшн ( не при первой загрузке)

```
02-07 19:21:24.488 5577-5577/com.jamesb.encoderyapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.jamesb.encoderyapp, PID: 5577
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 4, found: 8 Pager id: com.jamesb.encoderyapp:id/pager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.jamesb.encoderyapp.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1000)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity mActivity;
private ArrayList<JsonParsed> mApodData = new ArrayList<>();
private Utils mUtils;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<JsonParsed> mApodData) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mApodData = mApodData;
    mUtils = new Utils();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mApodData.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public View instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.mPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    viewHolder.mPicTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picTitle);
    viewHolder.mDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    itemView.setTag(viewHolder);

    JsonParsed item = mApodData.get(position);
    String descr = item.explanation;
    String title = item.title;
    String picUrl = item.hdurl;
    viewHolder.mPicTitle.setText(title);
    viewHolder.mDescription.setText(descr);

    Picasso.with(mActivity)
            .load(String.valueOf(picUrl))
            .into(viewHolder.mPic);

    viewHolder.mPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mUtils.setImageAsWallpaper(mActivity, viewHolder.mPic);
        }
    });
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);

}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mPic;
    TextView mPicTitle;
    TextView mDescription;
}
```

}

**...Fragment**

```
 try {
        RestClient.getInstance(getActivity()).getContent(date, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                String json = response.body().string();
                Log.d("---", json);
                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                mGson = gsonBuilder.create();
                jsonParsed = mGson.fromJson(json, JsonParsed.class);
                if (jsonParsed != null) mApodData.add(jsonParsed);
                if (count < iteration) {
                    count++;
                    getContent();
                } else {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mApodData);
                                mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

не могу понять где именно я не обновляю адаптер методом notifyDataSetChanged() и это приводит к исключению. Видел подобные вопросы в гугле,но что -то не нашел ответов,которые подействовали бы в моем случае. Подскажите решение. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вам при втором скачивании не надо заново назначать адаптер. Нужно лишь уведомить его, что значение (т.е. кол-во эл-тов в списке)  `mApodData` изменилось. При этом, эту переменную вам надо не переинициализировать в методе `onResponse`, а добавлять в существующий список методом `ArrayList#addAll(Collection c);`, после чего вызвать  `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

При первой загрузке всё должно остаться в коде как есть. Последующие загрузки вы можете определить проверив длину списка `mApodData`. Если она больше нуля, то загружаете вы не впервые и, значит, вам не надо создавать новый адаптер. Надо лишь уведомить его об изменении кол-ва элементов для отображения.

Comment: спасибо, работает)